# Set an ImageView from photo url

Tags: android, imageview, uri, firebase-authentication

How can I set an image to a **ImageView** from a URL?

Using Firebase authentication, I get the photo URL of the signed in user:

```
Uri uri = firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(0).getPhotoUrl();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Picasso Library to show images in ImageView.
You just need to pass the url, uri or resource to Picasso with image view.

like

```
Picasso.with(this).load(/* url of image */).into(/*your imageview id*/);
```

To use the picasso you need to add the following in Gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Read the documentation on http://square.github.io/picasso/

Also There are other libraries to display image in ImageView.
Like [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) etc

Comment: I use Picasso as it is very easy to implement - once Gradle synced, it can literally be as simple as 1 line of code. That's the kind of library I like!