# getting exceptions when loading facebook profile picture in android with facebook sdk 4+

Tags: java, android, facebook, asynchronous, authentication

im trying to load a facebook profile picture in my android app on thee top portion of a navigation drawer, but seem to be getting an exception. I have poured through stack overflows explaining how to load the image using bitmap, picasso, etc, but have been unable to load it for some reason still. I believe the issue is some network thread issue, but i thought that because i execute the method with .executeAsync() that it would not matter. 
Here is the xml where i declare the image that is to be a profile picture (nav_header_main.xml):

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/hanger_circle"
    app:border_color="#FF000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the snippet from my activity where i request the picture (on success of facebook login:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //initialize facebook sdk
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //call custom application class to initialize intercom (not login, just setup)
    ApplicationHelper helper = (ApplicationHelper)getApplicationContext();

    //create facebook button recognition
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    //facebook picture stuff
                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                    params.putString("fields", "id,email,gender,cover,picture.type(large)");
                    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                    if (response != null) {
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                            if (data.has("picture")) {
                                                String profilePicUrl = data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                                                // set profile image to imageview using Picasso or Native methods
                                                Bitmap profilePic = getFacebookProfilePicture(profilePicUrl);
                                                ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
                                                mImageView.setImageBitmap(profilePic);
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }).executeAsync();



                    // launch next activity
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


    //check if facebook user is logged in already
    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    Profile prof = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    if(token != null && prof != null){
        //log in
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), token.getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    //check if regular user is logged in already
    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("shared", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(shared.contains("username") && shared.contains("password")){
        //password exists in file so launch next activity (make sure there correct with API)
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }


}
```

I also use this helper method:

```
public static Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String url){
    URL facebookProfileURL= null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        facebookProfileURL = new URL(url);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(facebookProfileURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Here is my exception: 
05-26 14:20:05.751 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-26 14:20:05.751 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
05-26 14:20:05.751 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
05-26 14:20:05.751 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
05-26 14:20:05.751 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
05-26 14:20:05.751 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.press.press.LoginActivity.getFacebookProfilePicture(LoginActivity.java:215)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.press.press.LoginActivity$1$1.onCompleted(LoginActivity.java:85)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1379)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-26 14:20:05.752 11101-11101/com.android.press.press W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Please let me know if im doing something wrong.I have tried a variety of sources but this seems to be the most popular answer. I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an input stream as used in this line

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(facebookProfileURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

You should use **Picasso Library** to show images in ImageView, passing the **url** (without initiating any connection and without using the input stream, but only using the **url** that was received from Facebook):

```
Picasso.with(this).load(/* url of image */).into(/*your imageview id*/);
```

as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37466680/4038549).