# Unable to show images from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using new Firebase Storage and uploading image and then getting the download url. After converting the download url to string, i am using it to display in my activity but it just shows download url.
I am using below code to upload image and get download url :

```
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Add Shop");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //do something with edt.getText().toString();

            Uri image_uri = getImageUri();
            enteredShopName = shopName.getText().toString();
            enteredShopDescription = shopDescription.getText().toString();

            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            // Create a storage reference from our app
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://myapp.com");
            StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child("shop_images");
            StorageReference selectimage_ref = imagesRef.child(image_uri.getLastPathSegment());

            // upload file to firebase storage
            selectimage_ref.putFile(image_uri).
            addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri download_url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    String string_download_url = download_url.toString();
                    Shop shop = new Shop(enteredShopName, enteredShopDescription,string_download_url);
                    listRef.push().setValue(shop, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                            if (databaseError != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write message", databaseError.toException());
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Shop added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

After getting url i am setting it as shown to show image :

```
        public void setImg_url(String string_download_url){
        TextView field = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_shopImg);
        field.setText(string_download_url);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show images you should use **ImageView**.

You can use **Picasso** Library to show images in **ImageView**. You just need to pass the url, uri or resource to Picasso with image view.

like

```
Picasso.with(this).load(/* url of image */).into(/*your imageview id*/);
```

To use the picasso you need to add the following in Gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37466680/4038549).

Comment: When i am writing the above line i am not able to set context. I am using picasso in ViewHolder of RecyclerView

Comment: Try sending the Activity as a parameter

Comment: Tried it says cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: Can you please add to your question the code of the **ViewHolder**, were you use and implement **setImg_url**. I'm trying to understand the structure of the application...

Comment: Got it used view.getContext()